# php.ini settings getting ignored on XAMPP

Tags: xampp, php

I set up an install of *XAMPP* to build an ecommerce site using OpenCart. I put the OpenCart install on

```
C:\xampp\htdocs\opencart\upload
```

and I set the `php.ini` file in it and set

```
memory_limit = 1G
max_execution_time = 600.
```

The problem I'm having is that these settings are getting overwritten by something. When I run `phpinfo()`, it shows `memory_limit` as **128M** and `max_execution_time = 30`.

Comment: you can't just dump .ini files anywhere you want, not unless you put a directive into the main .ini's to include it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you putting the `php.ini` file inside of that directory? Because that's not where it belongs. You should take a look at the output of `phpinfo()` again. It will tell you that file that it is reading the configuration settings from. That is the file you need to update.